# Exceeding maximum number of variable declarations in script on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

An application I am currently working on will generate an SQL script to populate a database.  A single transaction in the script looks like this (note I have changed table/variable names ;-)

```
USE MyDatabase

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET XACT_ABORT ON
DECLARE @Foo int

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 ON 
INSERT INTO Table1 [...]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table1 OFF 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table2 ON 
INSERT INTO Table2 [...]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table2 OFF 

INSERT INTO Table3 [...]

-- Here I reference @Foo
SET @Foo = dbo.SomeStoredProcedure()
-- Use @Foo in some query

COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
```

This script will then generate `n` of these transactions, which will then be excuted on SQL Server 2005 to populate the database with `n` records.

The problem I am seeing is with the declaration of the `@Foo` variable shown above.  When running the script, once we have reached 65535 records, I get the following error:

```
The variable name '@Foo' has already been declared.
Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

I think this is a misleading error message, because everything is fine until I hit 65535, and the significance of this number (2^16-1) leads me to believe I am hitting some sort of script limitation.

I have tried defining the `@Foo` variable once, at the top of the script, and re-using it within each transaction.  But this doesn't work as it appears each transaction has its own scope.

Would creating an extra level of scope (i.e. an inner transaction) and declaring the variable within the deeper scope help address this issue?

Any other recommendations about the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: Could whatever is generating these scripts be hitting a limit, rather than SQL Server - E.g. if you inspect the script, does the #65535 look the same as the previous ones? Also, if your hitting any limit like this, does this process still make sense? Have you considered other options for importing this data?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've missed the **GO** delimiter, since I have scripts with *many* more lines. Check your scripting solution

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  I want to execute each batch (between each `GO` statement) once, so not sure how this helps me.

Comment: Can you create script and NOT run it, but inspect? Try to run it from SSMS - and in case of error it will point you to the error line

Comment: The script is 170MB, and when I try to open it in SSMS I'm getting an error "The operation could not be completed".  Looks like I'm not the first person to experience this: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/269566/sql-server-management-studio-cant-handle-large-files

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat Oops! The Sql Server limitation on script size is 120 Mb per batch - see if the one query between two **GO** not exceeds 120 Mb, else try to divide it to smaller parts.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "GO" delimiter?  What have I missed?

Comment: In your script after COMMIT TRANSACTION

Comment: The batch size is similar to above - only about 20 lines or so.  It is nowhere near 120 Mb per batch.

Comment: But why do you say I have missed the GO delimiter when it is in my code above?

Comment: If you missed some GO deep into the script - then you'll have double definition of @foo which is prohibited

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6953/discussion-between-oleg-dok-and-leopardskinpillboxhat)

Answer (score -1):

Try The Go delimiter and also change the data type for the dynmc. variable. You are going out of its range and an "INT" is a cyclic data type in SQL Servers. It will come to the same address when the cycle of -65536 to 65535 completes.

Comment: `int` is 4 bytes in SQL Server, so that doesn't explain why it's wrapping at 65535: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "GO" delimiter?  What have I missed?